# Where is the Weka dataset folder on mac

Tags: weka

I installed weka recently for a class in machine learning that I am taking and have been told that certain datasets are available in the weka folder called data.  I installed the mac version of weka found at this [link](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/downloading_weka/) but I don't seem to have the sample datasets nor can I find them when I search on my mac through spotlight search.  Does anyone know the location that mac would have them.  Or does anyone have a link to the sample data folder online that I can download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a Mac user, but you can find the datasets in the Weka git repository:

https://git.cms.waikato.ac.nz/weka/weka/-/tree/main/trunk/wekadocs/data

Or you can download them (and more) from sourceforge.net:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/datasets/

The UCI datasets, which make up a large portion of the Weka example datasets, are available from this location:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/datasets/UCI%20and%20StatLib/

Answer (score 3):

For macOS, you can find the dataset files by right-click Weka in "Applications", click "Show Package Contents" then within the directory `Contents/app/data`.

Example, on my mac the location is:
`./System/Volumes/Data/Applications/weka-3.8.6.app/Contents/app/data/`